# Python discord bot errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, python-3.9

I am getting the

```
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
```

error in python when trying to run my bot. Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Projects\disco bot\ppap", line 20, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 577, in login
    raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__.__name__} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
```

This is my code:

```
import discord
import os
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I dont have any extra files with the code. This is the only file in the project.
How would i fix the error? Thanks!

I have looked on other peoples posts but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` Your environment does not contain a TOKEN variable, so `os.getenv()` returned None.  How are you setting the TOKEN variable?

Comment: i am replacing TOKEN with the actual token so it would look like client.run(os.getenv('This_Is_A_Discord_Token'))

Comment: If you're doing that, you need to replace the whole `os.getenv()` call.  You obviously don't have an actual environment variable named `432643264236478gdfsjgfsj`.  Change that to `client.run('432643264236478gdfsjgfsj')`

Comment: And how would I go about that?

Comment: The purpose of `os.getenv('TOKEN')` is to fetch the value of an environment variable named TOKEN.  But if you're putting the actual token value in the code, then you don't need to fetch it from the environment at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Token` Value Must Be A **String**

So , If You Are Using .env File For Token 
Use Something Like :

`import os`
`from dotenv import load_dotenv` **# pip install dotenv**
`load_dotenv()` **# Load Every .env file in the application path**

`.... # Stuff`

`bot.run(os.getenv("BOTTOKEN"))`